# How can I make my game launcher go in about:blank without it just breaking?

Tags: google-sites

I am trying to make my game launcher open the in about:blank, but I need help to make it do that, since i'm not familiar with coding

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 
 <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
     <title>Product Card UI Design HTML CSS</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="ui.css">
 </head>
 
 <body>
     <section class="slider">
         <div class="card">
             <div class="card-content">
                 <img src="//image:data here//" alt="" class="card-img">
                 <h1 class="card-title"> //Game title// </h1>
                 <div class="card-body">
                     <div class="card-star">
                         <span class="rating-value">4.5</span>
                         <span class="star">&#9733;</span>
                     </div>
                     <p class="card-price"> //Description// </p>
                 </div>
                 <div class="card-footer">
<a href="https://generator.qr-code.co.za/4df9205223df4b508d38827606140f31/_rhsoKGSz://GTQ.SO/WRQk/2tju3HA3hkf~Hj/14rb/ZVDD9Ysy.Drvv"
                     <button class="btn btn-success">Play now!!</button></a>
                    
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
        
         </div>
     </section>
 </body>

 <style>
    :root {
    --primary: #18253c;
    /* --primary: #fff; */
    --secondary: #00dd53;
    --bg: #0e1523;
    /* --bg: #f5f5f5; */
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slider {
   
    padding: 1rem;

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    place-items: center;
    grid-gap: 2rem;

    font: normal 1rem sans-serif;
}

.card {
    position: relative;
    width: 17rem;
    height: 23rem;
    background-color:var(--primary);
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    border: .1rem solid transparent;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 .2rem .6rem #0003;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

.card:hover {
    border: .1rem solid var(--secondary);
    transform: scale(1.05);
}

.card::before, .card::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    background-color: var(--secondary);
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 100;
}

.card::before {
    top: -6%;
    right: -6%;
    width: 9rem;
    height: 9rem;
}

.card::after {
    bottom: -6%;
    left: -6%;
    width: 5rem;
    height: 5rem;
}

.card:hover::before {
    transform: scale(1.8);
}

.card:hover::after {
    transform: scale(0);
}

.card-content {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 200;
}

.card-img, 
.card-title {
    transform: translateY(4rem);
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

.card-img {
    width: auto;
    height: 9.5rem;
}

.card-title {
    font-size: 25px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    transition-delay: .1s;
}

.card-body, 
.card-footer {
    transform: translateY(8rem);
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

.card-body {
    width: 100%;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;

    transition-delay: .2s;
}

.card:hover .card-img,
.card:hover .card-title,
.card:hover .card-body,
.card:hover .card-footer {
    transform: translateY(0);
}

.card-footer {
    transition-delay: .3s;
}

.star {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    color: gold;
}

.card-price {
    font: bolder 15px sans-serif;
}

.btn {
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
    background-color: unset;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 2rem;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-success {
    background-color: var(--secondary);
}

.btn-border {
    border: .1rem solid var(--secondary);
}
 </style>
 
 </html>
```

When I attempt to add code from an preexisting about:blank cloak from here https://jsfiddle.net/kcx8aeno/, it just broke it instead.

I wanted it to load the content in about:blank, so I inserted code I got from jsfiddle, but all it did was break it.